# saving tab page to settings vb

Tags: vb.net, tabs, settings

I'm trying to save the active tab page on closing the app/form and on next startup, have that tab show again, rather than the first one. Tried using settings, with *(simplified)* approach below:

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab = My.Settings._frmTab
end sub

' Stuff

Public Sub Form1_Close(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
My.Settings._frmTab = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab
End Sub
```

Type in Settings set to: `System.Windows.Forms.TabPage`

No joy. Seems to work for other types like `System.Drawing` etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use settings like that.  Possibly if you assign an ID for each tab and stored the ID in the settings....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save the TabControl's Selected Index as integer.

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    tabControlMain.SelectedIndex = My.Settings.SelectedTab
End Sub

Private Sub Main_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    My.Settings.SelectedTab = tabControlMain.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```